# onBlur with useState hook not working in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm new into testing code with react and jest; and jest is having a strange behavior towards hooks.

This is my component. It has 2 useState hooks, linked to 2 functions.

- HandleChange will be triggered with onChange, and set the cardNumber with setCardNumber().
- HandleBlur will be triggered with onBlur, and set the cardType with setCardType().

Just a simple component that works as it should.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const Test = () => {
  const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState('');
  const [cardType, setCardType] = useState('');

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setCardNumber(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleOnBlur = () => {
    setCardType(cardNumber);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={cardNumber} onChange={handleOnChange} onBlur={handleOnBlur} />
      <p id="cn">{`CardNumber: ${cardNumber}`}</p>
      <p id="ct">{`CardType: ${cardType}`}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is the test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {Test} from '.';
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe('Sandbox Test', () => {
  it('should set cardNumber when doing onChange', async () => {
    const component = shallow(<Test />);

    const inputComponent = component.find('input');
    const value = {target: {value: '123456'}};

    await act(async () => {
      inputComponent.props().onChange(value);
      await component.update();
    });

    const cardNumberComponent = component.find('#cn');
    const cardTypeComponent = component.find('#ct');

    expect(cardNumberComponent.text()).toEqual(`CardNumber: 123456`);
    expect(cardTypeComponent.text()).toEqual(`CardType: `);
  });

  it('should set cardType when doing onBlur', async () => {
    const component = shallow(<Test />);

    const inputComponent = component.find('input');
    const value = {target: {value: '123456'}};

    await act(async () => {
      inputComponent.props().onChange(value);
      inputComponent.props().onBlur();
      await component.update();
    });

    const cardNumberComponent = component.find('#cn');
    const cardTypeComponent = component.find('#ct');

    expect(cardNumberComponent.text()).toEqual(`CardNumber: 123456`);
    expect(cardTypeComponent.text()).toEqual(`CardType: 123456`);
  });
});
```

I dunno what's happening when the onBlur action is triggered (I know it's been triggered), but somehow, it doesn't trigger setCardType(); and thus, this is the error I get when running the tests:

[image: Console Error while Testing]

What am I doing wrong? Been trying to debug this for the past couple of hours, and I'm sincerely clueless about what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the call to `.udpate()` recreates the node tree with all the updated data but doesn't automatically update references to nodes you get with `find()`. So, the `inputComponent` you have the moment you simulate the `onBlur` event is the instance of the first render with an old version of the `onBlur` handler with an empty value in `cardNumber` state. You need to grab the input node again to get an updated instance before firing the `onBlur` event.

```js
    ...
    let inputComponent = component.find("input"); 
    const value = { target: { value: "123456" } };

    await act(async () => {
      inputComponent.props().onChange(value);
      await component.update();
      inputComponent = component.find("input");
      inputComponent.props().onBlur();
      await component.update();
    });
    ...
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/input-onchange-onblur-enzyme-kdg0u?file=/src/MyComponent.test.tsx

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the explanation!!